# load picture in Div without Stretch and Need Scaling also using CSS?

Tags: html, css

Need help in to load image into div without Stretch and Do scaling as well but using CSS.
i have already try few Examples but they are not working. below are those examples,

```css
.img-contain {
      width: 550px;
      height: 220px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .myimage {
      min-width: 100%;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="img-contain">
  <img src="http://wallpapers111.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Beautiful-Scene-Wallpapers-Hd-1.jpg" class="myimage" />
</div>
```

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: is it i need to add after min-width: 100% ?

Comment: use `.myimage {
    max-width: 100%;
}`

Comment: **@tamil Selvan** not working properly. complete image is not going to fit inside the DIV

Comment: use `.myimage{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code is saying right now.
Your image will have a minimum width of the image-contain which is 300px wide.

If you want the image to scale as well as keep it's aspect ratio try this code out;

```
.myimage{
    width:100%;
}
```

Don't set the width of the img-contain to be a fixed width if you want it to scale with the size of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting a minimum width I would suggest using a media query, then setting a max-width: 100%; and height: auto; or your image will be distorted. This will make your page responsive.

```
.myimage { max-width: 100%; height: auto;}



@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
}
```

}

That would be for mobile portrait. IPhone

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
}
```

}

Landscape and so on.

Comment: **@user3758480** Appreciate your Help.if possible then please write the code a bit proper? bcoz difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm on my mobile, so it is a bit hard to format properly, but if you need clarification please let me know. That should fix your problem though.

Comment: **@user3758480** Actually how i can apply the above code ? is it i need to write it down under the Style TAG ? bcoz i try to write under the Style Tag but it is not working?

Comment: Ok, so you are not using a style sheet. The media queries should go at the bottom inside the style tag. Also make sure you add an additional closing }

Comment: below is the link of Image. this is very long in height but the width is very small? please have a look on it.

http://pocketlink.epocketlife.com/ImageRepository/images/events/ADEBAB1C-4FAF-4D65-A43D-A02978B76340/7adb104b-5140-45d9-a694-56cf5112917d.png

Comment: On PC now look above and it should make more sense.

Comment: Look below, that is how you will get the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
.myimage { max-width: 100%; height: auto;}


@media only screen {
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
 }
}

@media only screen {
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
 }
}
```